# Certain mysql column info wont display PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP site that I made that has an option to edit your account. On the edit account page, I have the username, Real Name, email, and password displayed. Everything display's perfectly except for the real name, which comes up as a blank. It displays fine on my memberlist page.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: login.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 

// This if statement checks to determine whether the edit form has been submitted 
// If it has, then the account updating code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
    } 

    // If the user is changing their E-Mail address, we need to make sure that 
    // the new value does not conflict with a value that is already in the system. 
    // If the user is not changing their E-Mail address this check is not needed. 
    if($_POST['email'] != $_SESSION['user']['email']) 
    { 
        // Define our SQL query 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        // Define our query parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // Retrieve results (if any) 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This E-Mail address is already in use"); 
        } 
    } 

    // If the user entered a new password, we need to hash it and generate a fresh salt 
    // for good measure. 
    if(!empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // If the user did not enter a new password we will not update their old one. 
        $password = null; 
        $salt = null; 
    } 

    // Initial query parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'], 
        ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'], 
    ); 

    // If the user is changing their password, then we need parameter values 
    // for the new password hash and salt too. 
    if($password !== null) 
    { 
        $query_params[':password'] = $password; 
        $query_params[':salt'] = $salt; 
    } 

    // Note how this is only first half of the necessary update query.  We will dynamically 
    // construct the rest of it depending on whether or not the user is changing 
    // their password. 
    $query = " 
        UPDATE users 
        SET 
            email = :email 
    "; 

    // If the user is changing their password, then we extend the SQL query 
    // to include the password and salt columns and parameter tokens too. 
    if($password !== null) 
    { 
        $query .= " 
            , password = :password 
            , salt = :salt 
        "; 
    } 

    // Finally we finish the update query by specifying that we only wish 
    // to update the one record with for the current user. 
    $query .= " 
        WHERE 
            id = :user_id 
    "; 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Now that the user's E-Mail address has changed, the data stored in the $_SESSION 
    // array is stale; we need to update it so that it is accurate. 
    $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $_POST['email']; 

    // This redirects the user back to the members-only page after they register 
    header("Location: private.php"); 

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
    die("Redirecting to private.php"); 
} 

?> 
<h1>Edit Account</h1> 
<div class="body">
<form action="edit_account.php" method="post"> 
Name:<br /> 
<b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
</b> 
<br><br> 
Username:<br /> 
<b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b> 
<br /><br /> 
E-Mail Address:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']       
    ['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
<br /><br /> 
Password:<br /> 
<input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /> 
<i>(leave blank if you do not want to change your password)</i> 
<br /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Update Account" /> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: both in Name and Username, you echo $_SESSION['user']['username']. you can check your session values by running `print_r($_SESSION)` in your php code, or even `print_r($_SESSION['user'])`

Comment: Give brief code line, Where you have actual problem..

Comment: The real name is not put in the session variable. The username is. The part where the username is put in the session is not in the question. It's hard to give an easy answer that way.

Comment: I saw that I had username instead of name put in, but even after fixing it I'm encountering the problem.